# Heart Animation displaying in android

Tags: android

I am using the following animation to get the Heart blowing effect in android,but the animation is looking like heart symbol is getting small and then bigger,but I want the viceversa effect(first it should become large and then small).

I really didnt understand how to modify this Animation for getting that large image.

Animation Used:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="0.5" />
```

Please help me in solving this issue.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are looking for something like this. Edit the from/to scales to achieve the effect you are looking for.

```
   <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5" />
```

Comment: I have one more can I ask you

Comment: Thanks,I want to change to background of Relative layout to Circle shape(before it is half-circle).I am doing this in my ontouchListener class

Comment: Could you explain a little better?

Comment: Here I explained with my coding  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651172/circular-image-is-changing-to-oval-shape-while-changing-background

Answer (score 1):

Try this this animation..animates the view to the small and large and vice versa

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:duration="1000"
  android:fromXScale="0.5"
  android:fromYScale="0.5"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="50%"
  android:repeatCount="infinite"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  android:toXScale="1.5"
  android:toYScale="1.5" />
```