# Circular image is changing to Oval shape while changing Background

Tags: android

I want to set the Background of layout to Circular shape( before it is half circle).

I am doing this in my onTouchListener as below[image]

As you can see the below Half circle image and Full image.

But when I tries to change background by using the following line,my circle gets changed to oval shape,I didnt understand why its happening.

```
 Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinkcircle);

     view.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
```

MyTouchListener class:

```
     half_left=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.half_left);
     half_left.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());

  private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

            Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinkcircle);

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    view.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
                  } else {

                    return false;
                  }


            }
          }
```

[image]

Please help in solving this issue.

Comment: Can you post an image of the oval shape you are getting?

Comment: Try defining co-ordinates and check if it helps.

Comment: I didnt get you Ibungo

Comment: yes Matt, did you get my Oval image